# Laravel - Seeding strategy for tables with foreign keys

Tags: laravel, seeding

I have an application that I want to port over to Laravel.

It already has data so I would need to port and set the database data using Migration and Seeding.

In my app, I have Table `foo` and Table `bar`. A field in Table `bar` is a foreign key to a field in Table `foo`.

When I seed, the id's inserted would most likely be different from the old application.

The problem then is that the integrity of the foreign key fields would be compromised since the ids' would be different.

Is there any strategy to solve this issue? I don't mind changing the values of the foreign key fields as long as it points to the correct row.

Comment: [This](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-database-seeding/) or [this one](http://php.dzone.com/articles/why-laravel-4s-seeds-and) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Does not depend of the language or framework, Laravel, Rails... the logic stays same.

You have to do some smarts `select` on `bar` table to be able to link `foo` to `bar`.

So in **Laravel** context you open `FooTableSeeder.php` and write something like this:

```
$bar1 = Bar::where( ---your condition---)->first();
$bar2 = Bar::where( ---your condition---)->first();

DB::table('foo')->truncate();

$foogees = array(
  array( 'bar_id' => $bar1->id ...),
  array( 'bar_id' => $bar1->id ...),
  array( 'bar_id' => $bar2->id ...),
  ...
);

DB::table('foo')->insert($foogees);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. My solution was to manually input the `foo` id's. It worked well for me.

Normally, I wouldn't recommend setting the primary keys for a table, but since you're porting it, I think this is one of those situations where it would be acceptable.